# Python: Is there any built-in function which typecasts string to unsigned integer only, throw error if string is signed integer

Tags: python, typecasting-operator

Consider this example in Python 3.X:

```
strX = "-5"
print (int(strX))
```

Above program returns **-5**

**Question:** Is there any built-in function similar to "int()" which returns an error message if the string to be converted (in the above example **"strX"**) is a negative number?

I am looking for some built-in function like "unsigned_int()" which should only proceed if the string passed has zero or above number, else return an error if a negative number is passed.

Comment: No, that would be a weirdly specific builtin. But it's pretty easy to write that function yourself.

Comment: You could just parse it as an int, then throw if it parses as negative. Afaik, Python doesn't have unsigned integers, so this would just be a matter of making sure the result is positive.

Comment: an inpoerformant way would be to check `all(x.isdigit() for x in strX)` and if not it is no positive integer. - it is better to `try: x = int(strX); if x <0: raise ValueError; except ValueError: ...`

Comment: `int` isn't a function it's a `class`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing builtin for this, Python only recognizes "int" type. You can check if there is (or are) any `'-'` before the actual digits, and if so, using `%` to determine if their count is even or odd, determine if it should be positive or negative.

Do not forget that 0 and -0 should both be positive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a one-liner or built-in function for that specific purpose, but a simple if statement should work.

```
strX = "-5"
strX = int(strX)
if strX >= 0 or strX >= -0:
  print (strX)
else:
  print ("Not a non-negative value.")
```

Your example was written with Python 2.7 syntax, but since I am not comfortable with that, I rewrote it in Python 3.X. Sorry for the inconvenience.